# How to add error channel to gather & scatter in application context xml?

Tags: spring-integration

Hello Spring Integration Users,

I wish to route all errors in gather and scatter pattern to be handled gracefully and apply some business logic. But I do not see any place holder to specify error channel in gather and scatter. Below is how my application context XML looks like:

```
<int:scatter-gather
    id="a_scatter_gather"
    input-channel="ip_channel"
    output-channel="op_success_channel">
    <int:scatterer>
        <int:recipient channel="a_input_channel"/>
        <int:recipient channel="b_input_channel"/>
    </int:scatterer>
    <int:gatherer 
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 2">
    </int:gatherer>
</int:scatter-gather>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `header-enricher` with its `error-channel` sub-element in advance of `scatter-gather`.